# How to change path of HTML attribute in Blueprism?

Tags: blueprism

I am reading values of school name from school data from a site. I can get all school name only by changing it's HTML attribute - path

/HTML/BODY(1)/FORM(1)/DIV(5)/DIV(2)/DIV(1)/DIV(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/DIV(6)/TABLE(***1000***)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)/TABLE(2)/TBODY(1)/TR(1)/TD(1)

From above path i want to change 1000 to 1001 or 1002 ...so that i can get different school name. I can change the path value using calculation and save in data item but how to save that value in original html Attribute path ??
 [click here to see image I want to change path value of SNo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyA1W.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it:

1. Make the Path of the element as dynamic in application modeler.

[image]

2. Get the HTML attribute value and store it in the data item (eg Path in the below figure)

[image]

3. Change the path value - use replace:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make the HTML Path as dynamic attribute instead of Equal, select Dynamic Option in application modeller. Then you can pass the required html path as an input at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Open Application modeller set the Xpath as Dynamic instead of equal
open navigate and add the element and from parameter add the path between ""
and remove the changable part and add your variable like this
"/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[4]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/UL["&[Counter]&"]/LI[8]/A[1]"